# Why an exception when I add a DataGridCell style?

Tags: wpf, itemssource, datagridcell

The following xaml gives the exception: "Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource."
In code behind we have simply:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DataContext = Customers;

    Customers.Add(new Customer { Voornaam = "Tom", Achternaam = "Jones" });
    Customers.Add(new Customer { Voornaam = "Joe", Achternaam = "Thompson" });
    Customers.Add(new Customer { Voornaam = "Jill", Achternaam = "Smith" });
}

private List<Customer> _customers = new List<Customer>();
public List<Customer> Customers { get { return _customers; }}

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" />
</DataGrid>
```

Without the Style there is no exception.
The fact that the Style is empty is just because I was looking for the minimal code that gives the exception. Adding a setter doesn't change anything.
The reaseon for the usage of the style is that I want to tweak the controltemplate for the autogenerated columns.

Comment: It seems you are trying to add the WPF Style programmatically. If this is a case, then remove that line from XAML and add style in C# code-behind module. Best regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your style is fine. The issue is how you apply the style to your `DataGrid`.

The way you define the style is like trying to say "let's inject the style to the `Content` of the `DataGrid`", and that's exactly why you see this error.

> Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.

Try using the following code to add the style to the `DataGrid`'s `CellStyle` property instead.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        </Style>        
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```